# is there combine function in spark just like hadoop combine function

Tags: apache-spark

As the title described, is there combine function in spark just like hadoop combine function for reducing the shuffle data transfer. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have a look at reduceByKey / combineByKey which does reduce the keys within partition before shuffling.

Comment: In addition using MapByPartition and other Partition based operations can help with that. e.g. if you are trying to find the max / min in a dataset. You can compute the max/min for every partition.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43364432/spark-difference-between-reducebykey-vs-groupbykey-vs-aggregatebykey-vs-combineb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [aggregateByKey](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions) it has an argument for combOp which is identical to a combiner. In most cleanly written code reduceByKey will automatically use the reduce function as the combiner