# Spark difference between reduceByKey vs. groupByKey vs. aggregateByKey vs. combineByKey

Tags: apache-spark, grouping, reducing

Can anyone explain the difference between `reducebykey`, `groupbykey`, `aggregatebykey` and `combinebykey`? I have read the documents regarding this, but couldn't understand the exact differences.

An explanation with examples would be great.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

**groupByKey:**

Syntax:

```
sparkContext.textFile("hdfs://")
                    .flatMap(line => line.split(" ") )
                    .map(word => (word,1))
                    .groupByKey()
                    .map((x,y) => (x,sum(y)))
```

`groupByKey` can cause out of disk problems as data is sent over the network and collected on the reduced workers.

**reduceByKey:**

Syntax:

```
sparkContext.textFile("hdfs://")
                    .flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
                    .map(word => (word,1))
                    .reduceByKey((x,y)=> (x+y))
```

Data are combined at each partition, with only one output for one key at each partition to send over the network. `reduceByKey` required combining all your values into another value with the exact same type.

**aggregateByKey:**

same as `reduceByKey`, which takes an initial value.

3 parameters as input

1. initial value
2. Combiner logic
3. sequence op logic

*Example:*

```
val keysWithValuesList = Array("foo=A", "foo=A", "foo=A", "foo=A", "foo=B", "bar=C", "bar=D", "bar=D")
    val data = sc.parallelize(keysWithValuesList)
    //Create key value pairs
    val kv = data.map(_.split("=")).map(v => (v(0), v(1))).cache()
    val initialCount = 0;
    val addToCounts = (n: Int, v: String) => n + 1
    val sumPartitionCounts = (p1: Int, p2: Int) => p1 + p2
    val countByKey = kv.aggregateByKey(initialCount)(addToCounts, sumPartitionCounts)
```

*ouput:*
Aggregate By Key sum Results
bar -> 3
foo -> 5

**combineByKey:**

3 parameters as input

1. Initial value: unlike `aggregateByKey`, need not pass constant always, we can pass a function that will return a new value.
2. merging function
3. combine function

*Example:*

```
val result = rdd.combineByKey(
                        (v) => (v,1),
                        ( (acc:(Int,Int),v) => acc._1 +v , acc._2 +1 ) ,
                        ( acc1:(Int,Int),acc2:(Int,Int) => (acc1._1+acc2._1) , (acc1._2+acc2._2)) 
                        ).map( { case (k,v) => (k,v._1/v._2.toDouble) })
        result.collect.foreach(println)
```

`reduceByKey`,`aggregateByKey`,`combineByKey` *preferred over* `groupByKey`

*Reference:*
[Avoid groupByKey](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html)

Comment: shouldn't someone add an `if clause` in the aggregate function to check if the combiner is just addition and if so use reduceByKey logic? Is there something I'm missing here to understand why that cant be done in compile time? Efficiency just by hard-coding the combiner means there should be such a check if not multiple such checks for common combiners in aggregate right?

Comment: These checks can even be done in parallel not getting in the way of the computation starting, and can optimize..

Answer (score 30):

- `groupByKey()` is just to group your dataset based on a key. It will result in data shuffling when RDD is not already partitioned.
- `reduceByKey()` is something like grouping + aggregation. We can say `reduceByKey()` equivalent to dataset.group(...).reduce(...). It will shuffle less data unlike `groupByKey()`.
- `aggregateByKey()` is logically same as `reduceByKey()` but it lets you return result in different type. In another words, it lets you have an input as type x and aggregate result as type y. For example (1,2),(1,4) as input and (1,"six") as output. It also takes *zero-value* that will be applied at the beginning of each key.

**Note:** One similarity is they all are wide operations.

Comment: Does someone know if there is a difference between `rdd.groupByKey`, `rdd.reduceByKey` and `sql.groupBy`? I have a large dataset and would like to use the most performant method. Thanks

Answer (score 19):

> While both reducebykey and groupbykey will produce the same answer, the
>   reduceByKey example works much better on a large dataset. That's
>   because Spark knows it can combine output with a common key on each
>   partition before shuffling the data.
>
> On the other hand, when calling groupByKey - all the key-value pairs
>   are shuffled around. This is a lot of unnessary data to being
>   transferred over the network.

for more detailed check this below link

https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html

Comment: Thanks all for the replies

Comment: Is there any circumstances where we should be using groupByKey ? What if the function is not an associative one ?

Answer (score 12):

Although both of them will fetch the same results, there is a significant difference in the performance of both the functions. `reduceByKey()` works better with larger datasets when compared to `groupByKey()`.

In `reduceByKey()`, pairs on the same machine with the same key are combined (by using the function passed into `reduceByKey()`) before the data is shuffled. Then the function is called again to reduce all the values from each partition to produce one final result.

In `groupByKey()`, all the key-value pairs are shuffled around. This is a lot of unnecessary data to being transferred over the network.

Answer (score 6):

**ReduceByKey** `reduceByKey(func, [numTasks])`-

Data is combined so that at each partition there should be at least one value for each key.
And then shuffle happens and it is sent over the network to some particular executor for some action such as reduce.

**GroupByKey** - `groupByKey([numTasks])`

It doesn't merge the values for the key but directly the shuffle process happens 
and here lot of data gets sent to each partition, almost same as the initial data.

And the merging of values for each key is done after the shuffle.
Here lot of data stored on final worker node so resulting in out of memory issue.

**AggregateByKey** - `aggregateByKey(zeroValue)(seqOp, combOp, [numTasks])`
It is similar to reduceByKey but you can provide initial values when performing aggregation.

Use of `reduceByKey`

- `reduceByKey` can be used when we run on large data set.
- `reduceByKey` when the input and output value types are of same type 
  over `aggregateByKey`

Moreover it recommended not to use `groupByKey` and prefer `reduceByKey`. For details you can refer [here](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html).

You can also refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24804619/how-does-spark-aggregate-function-aggregatebykey-work) to understand in more detail how `reduceByKey` and `aggregateByKey`.

Answer (score 2):

Then apart from these 4, we have

foldByKey which is same as reduceByKey but with a user defined Zero Value.

AggregateByKey takes 3 parameters as input and uses 2 functions for merging(one for merging on same partitions and another to merge values across partition. The first parameter is ZeroValue)

whereas

ReduceBykey takes 1 parameter only which is a function for merging.

CombineByKey takes 3 parameter and all 3 are functions. Similar to aggregateBykey except it can have a function for ZeroValue.

GroupByKey takes no parameter and groups everything. Also, it is an overhead for data transfer across partitions.