# Scala - How to convert a pair RDD to an RDD?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have an `RDD[Sale]` and wanted to leave only the latest sales. So what I did is created a pair RDD and then performed grouping and filtering:

```
val sales: RDD[(String, Sale)] = rawSales.map(sale => sale.id -> sale)
      .groupByKey()
      .mapValues(_.maxBy(_.timestamp))
```

But how do I return back to `RDD[Sale]` instead of the pair RDD in this case?

The only way I figured out is the following:

```
val value: RDD[Sale] = sales.map(salePaired => salePaired._2)
```

Is it the most proper solution?

Comment: RDD "rawSales" can be reused again.

Comment: @pasha701 but I need and RDD after filtering transformations

Comment: "sales.values" can be used

Comment: As a performance hint, in this case, prefer reduceByKey instead of groupByKey/mapValues . https://stackoverflow.com/a/47516081/2131074

Comment: @GPI thanks. But I'm having trouble implementing `reduceByKey` with `maxBy` like this.. `.reduceByKey( ???  => _.maxBy(_.timestamp) )`

Comment: @GPI Could you give a hint on how to implement `reduceByKey` with `maxBy` correctly?

Comment: @samba something along the lines of `.reduceByKey((sale1, sale2) => if (sale1.timestamp > sale2.timestamp) sale1 else sale2)`

Answer (score 1):

You can access the keys or values from pair RDD directly, like you access any Map

```
val keys: RDD[String] = sales.keys
val values: RDD[Sale] = sales.values
```